# Timemachine multiple passwords

Tags: time-machine, security, password, encryption, filevault

I have several standard user accounts on a Mac OS computer.

I have setup a timemachine backup. This backup is protected by a password. So files are encrypted on the external backup drive.

Each user can launch the backup. But he needs to know the Time Machine password.

If a user knows the timemachine password, he can other user's files on the external drive.

I want to prevent that:

- Is there a way to launch a backup without knowing the timemachine password ? (and be sure users cannot read files on the timemachine external drive)
- Or is there a way to set different timemachine password/encryption keys for each users ? At this time, the timemachine password is a "per drive" password. I would like a "per user" timemachine password.

Is there a way to do that ? Or are there alternatives ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: *"If a user knows the timemachine password, he can other user's files on the external drive."* Have you tested this? I can't test here, but I would be surprised if this was possible.

Comment: Of course this is possible. What I tried is to open the external drive on another computer

Comment: Of course, if you're an admin or move the drive, sure, because you can override any permissions. Your users have standard perms, so shouldn't be able to do that. If you want 3 encrypted backups, you'll need 3 partitions, one one each.

Comment: I can't test because i do not have hardware now. But do you think timemachine encryption key is merged with user password hash for example ? Thanks